# How to serve files based on filename's last three characters in nginx

Tags: regex, nginx, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, nginx-location

I am trying to serve files based on its filenames for example below is the filename

```
zielinski-6b7982e5-5743-41c4-a854-1257812e4be.jpeg
```

which resides inside below

```
/e/4b/zielinski-6b7982e5-5743-41c4-a854-1257812e4be.jpeg
```

now the last three characters of the filename is used for directory structuring i.e last character 'e' is the first directory and inside second last characters '4b' is the sub directory and inside it is the file 'zielinski-6b7982e5-5743-41c4-a854-1257812e4be.jpeg' that exist

I was able to get filename from request url by using below map in nginx

```
map $basename $filenameOne {
    ~(?<abx>\\.[^\\.]*)$ $abx;
    }
```

so the result i got from above map is 'zielinski-6b7982e5-5743-41c4-a854-1257812e4be.jpeg' but i want the directory structure as mentioned above to serve those files can this be done using rewrite regex in nginx or do i need to use location regex any help would be great

Comment: ServerFault.com is a better place to ask server configuration questions like this.

Comment: Its also a regex question so i thought if someone could help me out with a regex

Comment: Regexp: `(..)(.)\\.[^\\.]*$` `$1` is `4b` and `$2` is `e`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the regex was a big help but to specifically answer my own question here's how i did it I used below map to get my folder structure

```
map $uri $directory {
~(?<suffix>(..)(.).[^.]*)$ /$3/$2/;
}
```

Now the above map will give me

```
/e/4b/
```

which i use at the location directive of nginx like below

```
location /test/ {

alias /home/fileTest/$directory;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this regex:

```
^([^.]*)(\w{2})(\w).*$
```

and capture the directory(including the filename) by the following:

```
/\3/\2/\0
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cE3OK7/2/)**

**Explanation:**

- `^` - asserts the start of the line
- `^([^.]*)` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character that is not a `.` and capture it in group 1
- `(\w{2})` - match 2 word-characters and capture it in group 2
- `(\w{1})` - match 1 word-character and capture it in group 3
- `.*` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character except a newline
- `$` - asserts the end of the line